# Disappearing radio button and clickable labels

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to make radio buttons disappear and instead of buttons, the label of the radio buttons will be clickable itself and i will change the background color of the selected radio. How can i do this? For example, I have "yes" and "no" labels and these labels will be clickable and there will be no radio buttons at all. These are only changing color of background but showing radio buttons which is not wanted.

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var ok = "green";
    var notok = "red";

    $.each($(":radio"), function(){

        if($(this).prop("checked") == false)
        {
            $(this).parent().css("background", notok);
        }
        else
        {
            $(this).parent().css("background", ok );
        }
    })

    $(":radio").click(function(){
        $("[name='"+$(this).prop("name")+"']").parent().css("background", notok);
        $(this).parent().css("background", ok );

    })
})
```

HTML

```
<FORM name="form1">
 <div>
        <input type="radio" id="yes" name="q"checked="checked"/> Yes
        </div>
        <div>
        <input type="radio" id="no" name="q"/>No
        </div>


</FORM>
```

Thanks

Comment: So why do you need `radio` buttons? Make it 2 `<div>`-s and put the selected value into a hidden field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you're asking, I'd hide the radio buttons, then attach a click handler to the labels that changed the background color:

```
$('label').click(function () {
   $('label').removeClass('selected');
   $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AcWrf/1/) to demonstrate.

In short, when a label is clicked, remove the 'selected' class controlling the background color from all relevant labels, and apply it to the one that was clicked.

Answer (score 2):

This one is actually deceptively easy. If you just use a "label" tag, it will be clickable. Then you can simply hide the radio button.

```
<input id="yes" type="radio" name="q" value="radiobutton" style="display:none;" />
<label for="yes">Yes </label>

<input id="no" type="radio" name="q" value="radiobutton" style="display:none;" />
<label for="no">No</label>
```

btw, here's a JSFiddle of it working: http://jsfiddle.net/scGE9/2/

Comment: I had the exact same code typed out and I was ready to click post when your answer showed up.

Comment: sorry! I hate it when that happens.